# Convert number to currency using Informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I'm trying to figure out the best way to convert numbers into currency using Informatica. For example, I want to convert 4000 to $4,000.00. I think the Java tx is the way to go but I have never used it and I'm unable to find examples of how to code it properly so that it works. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Gary

Comment: One more thing. I know I can do this in SQ using Oracle but our customer prefers that I not modify the source query.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in Expression Transformation without using Java. Of course, this is kind of static, but you can always code it for maximum possible amount.

```
v_AMT_STR := TO_CHAR(TO_DECIMAL(TO_CHAR(inp_AMT),2)) 

v_LEN := LENGTH(v_AMT_STR) 

v_THSND_SEP := DECODE(TRUE,
    IN(v_LEN,7,8,9), SUBSTR(v_AMT_STR,0,v_LEN-6)||','||SUBSTR(v_AMT_STR,-6),
    IN(v_LEN,10,11,12), SUBSTR(v_AMT_STR,0,v_LEN-9)||','||SUBSTR(v_AMT_STR,-9,3)||','||SUBSTR(v_AMT_STR,-6),
    IN(v_LEN,13,14,15), SUBSTR(v_AMT_STR,0,v_LEN-12)||','||SUBSTR(v_AMT_STR,-12,3)||','||SUBSTR(v_AMT_STR,-9,3)||','||SUBSTR(v_AMT_STR,-6),
    v_AMT_STR) 

o_CURRENCY := '$'||v_THSND_SEP
```

`inp_AMT` is decimal input port

`v_` and `o_` are variable and output ports respectively

It supports up to $999,999,999,999.99. You can add more lines in the DECODE above to go beyond that.

Comment: You did not account for v_LEN equal to 4, 5, or 6.